# Proguard obfuscate entire package but one file

Tags: android, proguard, android-gradle-plugin

I have a package named `com.my.app.utils`. I want to obfuscate everything in it but one file, which we could call `MadUtils.java`

In my proguard-rules.txt, I have:

`-keep class !com.my.app.utils.** { *; }`

This clearly obfuscates everything under `com.my.app.utils`.

I don't know how to tell what files were obfuscated by proguard, so I couldn't check, but I was hoping the following would work:

```
-keep class !com.my.app.utils.** { *; }
-keep class com.my.app.utils.MadUtils { *; }
```

where the first line says it'll obfuscate everything, but then the second line saves MadUtils from the obfuscation. I couldn't get a clear understanding from the Proguard docs about whether this would work.

Comment: -keep means its not apply the obfuscate  for what put as keep.

Comment: The `-keep class !com.my.app.utils.** { *; }` obfuscates because of the `!`. So, keep everything else, but obfuscate `com.my.app.utils.** { *; }`

Comment: I don't think you need to tell proguard to "obfuscate everything", because this is what it does - obfuscates. Just use `-keep class com.my.app.utils.MadUtils { *; }`. Btw, you can use [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/) to decompile the apk and see if your class is being obfuscated.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
-keep class com.my.app.utils.MadUtils, !com.my.app.utils.** { *; }
```

Comment: The order is very important for obfuscate a package and exclude one file, thanks for this.